# [wso2][vfs] file note moved not moving after sucess processing

Tags: wso2, vfs

i created proxy file in order to moving file to another directory.
the file has been processed,deleted and not moved.
can you plese tell whats wrong in my services :

```html
<proxy name="http_proxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <log description="" level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://tmp/data/test</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vsf.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vsf.MoveAfterProcess">file://tmp/data/f</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: The file is deleted but not moved? Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: I cannot find errors, and any action related to moving file to "/tmp/data/f"  directory!!

Comment: In fact, it was an error at the parameter name. i put vsf instead of vfs. its resolved now.  Thanks